# Does the Settings page for ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT work? Android 14

Tags: android, android-14

I am trying to conform to the new Android 14 behavioural changes, specifically the changes regarding
[secure full-screen intent's](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#secure-fsi)

The documentation is quite specific, still I am having quite some trouble to implement what is being described :

> You can use the new API NotificationManager.canUseFullScreenIntent to check if your app has the permission; if not, your app can use the new intent ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT to launch the settings page where users can grant the permission.

I am testing on a Pixel 7 enrolled into the Android 14 Beta program and running the Beta 3.

So I am actually trying to do this like this

```
val nmgr = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager    
if (!nmgr.canUseFullScreenIntent())
{
    debug(TAG,"Running Android 14 AND no permission for using full screen intent, show settings page")
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT))
}
```

Unfortunately this results in the following error :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {MainActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT }

I am wondering if anyone has been testing this new change within the Android 14 Beta ?

---Update---
For now I kinda solved it like this :

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, packageName)
        .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

Comment: you can also write like this: `Inetnt(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT, Uri parse("package:my.package.name"))`, the `package` data is required as doc described "Input: the intent's data URI **must** specify the application package name for which you want to manage full screen intents.".

Comment: @Ayaka_Ago it is the main reason for this problem. the prefix `package:` should be present in the package name, without it the system just throws the `ActivityNotFoundException`. Could you please specify the link on the documentation where you found this

Comment: Works without parameters.