# jump to full screen notification settings. android 14

Tags: android, notifications, settings

Determine whether to enable full-screen notifications based on Google's latest API, and jump to the settings interface based on the intent provided by Google.but something went wrong
This is a Google Doc

> You can use the new API NotificationManager.canUseFullScreenIntent to check if the app has the permission; if not, the app can use the new intent ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT to launch a settings page where the user can grant the permission.

this is my code

```
button1.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
                if(!notificationManager.canUseFullScreenIntent()){
                     //method 1
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT)
                .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE,getPackageName())
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                //method 2
                startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT, Uri.parse(getPackageName())));
                }
            }
        });
```

But the following error occurs
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }
The device I'm using is Google Pixel 6a,I was wondering if anyone has tried it and had success

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem answered here.

[Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565961/does-the-settings-page-for-action-manage-app-use-full-screen-intent-work-androi)

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, packageName)
        .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
```

Comment: My first method is this,but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to open the full screen notification settings via without any success:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(
  Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT,
  Uri.parse("my.package.name")
)
startActivity(intent)
```

Tested the code on a Google Pixel 6a.

I currently fallback to just open the notification settings, as suggested earlier, via:

```kotlin
try {
    val intent = Intent(
        Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT,
        Uri.parse("my.package.name")
    )
    startActivity(intent)
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, "my.package.name")
        .addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK))
}
```